useFormState function wrapper makes my server action return void?
export function CreateClientForm({ closeDialog }: { closeDialog: () => void }) {
  const initialState: FormState = {
    message: null,
    errors: {},
    actionSuccess: null,
  }
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(createClient, initialState)
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof ClientFormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(ClientFormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      isNewClient: false,
    },
  })

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        action={async (formData) => {
          const result = await formAction(formData)
          console.log(state.message!)
          if (state.actionSuccess === true) {
            closeDialog()
            toast('Client Created Succesfully!')
          }
        }}
        className="w-full space-y-2"
      >

My server action returns formState which I could use to then see if it was succesful or not, but the issue is that formAction seems to be synchronous even though its an async function.
This causes the state to not be updated before the if condition is reached.
I tried using createClient directly without the useFormState wrapper but then I lose all the form validation I am getting from using formState. Is there a way to make formAction asynchronous while keeping my form state validation the same?
